# Why checkout -b does work only after second attempt?

Tags: git

```
$sudo git clone sample.git 

Cloning into 'sample'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
done.

$ cd sample

$ echo "hello world" > readme

$ git add readme

$ git checkout -b a
Switched to a new branch 'a'

$ git branch

$ git checkout master
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.

$ git checkout a
error: pathspec 'a' did not match any file(s) known to git.

$ git checkout -b b
Switched to a new branch 'b'

$ git branch

$ git commit -am .
[b (root-commit) 12b8434] .
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 go

$ git branch
* b

$ git checkout a
error: pathspec 'a' did not match any file(s) known to git.

$ git checkout -b a
Switched to a new branch 'a'

$ git branch
* a
  b
```

What was wrong with my first `checkout -b a`, why the branch was not created?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you told `git` to create a branch in an empty repository. There is no commit yet, and a branch is just a "sticky note" pointing to a commit. So what is `git` supposed to do...

At least it stores your new branch in `HEAD`, so the branch tip will be updated with future commits. As shown by your commit.

More fun with empty repositories:

```
~/tmp> mkdir empty
~/tmp> cd empty
~/tmp/empty> git init
Initialized empty Git repository in tmp/empty/.git/
~/tmp/empty> git log
fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'
~/tmp/empty> git branch xxx
fatal: Not a valid object name: 'master'.
~/tmp/empty> git checkout -b xxx
Switched to a new branch 'xxx'
~/tmp/empty> git log
fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'
~/tmp/empty> ls -l .git/
branches/    config       description  HEAD         hooks/       info/        objects/     refs/
~/tmp/empty> cat .git/HEAD
ref: refs/heads/xxx
~/tmp/empty> ls -l .git/refs/heads
total 0
```

EDIT: adopted the comment from @jthill.

Comment: You beat me by a few seconds :) yeah, git tends to behave in a funny way when there are no commits in the repository

Comment: This behavior is confusing. I found it after updating my Git to a newer version. Now `git init` creates a fake master branch. I just consider it as a bug.

Comment: Seems like somebody else considered it a bug as well. My example is from `git 2.0.4`.

Comment: To avoid a common misunderstanding I'd say "so the branch tip will be updated with future commits".