# Git --> error: src refspec master does not match any

Tags: git

Created a new repository and tried to push initial files to it. 
But there's this error:

```
~/RS-Card $ git push -u origin master
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:shipra1509/RS-Card.git'
```

Is there something wrong with the ssh keys?
If not this, how to resolve this error?

Comment: Do you have a local branched named `master`? What is the output of `git status`?  How about the output of `git branch`?

Comment: Run `git branch -a` and make sure you have `remotes/origin/master` in your result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you initialize a new repository, then you must add and commit some files before the branch master actually exists. See: [Why checkout -b does work only after second attempt?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38307567/4233593)

So try again:

```
git add .
git commit -m "commit message"
git push -u origin master
```